# Javascript function call with embedded object not working

Tags: javascript, json, function

I am creating some html on-the-fly as follows:

```
html += '<a class="ipadbutton" href="javascript:dashboard_GetProfileStats({&quot;profileid&quot;:&quot;' + profile.id + '&quot;});">Stats</a>';
```

When I hover over the link in chrome it looks ok (everything resolved, so link looks like this:

```
javascript:dashboard_GetProfileStats({"profileid":"blablabla"});
```

However, the link does not work in Chrome, or Safari.  Can you embed objects in hrefs like this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The &quot is bad syntax for javascript. It is displaying as a quote "'", but internally it is """, and this is causing the link to fail.

What you want is something more like:

```
html += "<a class=\"ipadbutton\" href=\"javascript:dashboard_GetProfileStats({'profileid': + profile.id});\">Stats</a>';
```

or even better

```
html += "<a class=\"ipadbutton\" href=\"\" onclick=\"dashboard_GetProfileStats({'profileid': + profile.id});\">Stats</a>';
```

*Also*, typically you use an event handler to deal with links and anchor tags.

so best is: (attaching the event via jquery)

```
html += '<a class="ipadbutton">Stats</a>';

<script>
  $(function() {
   $('.ipadbutton').click(function() {
     dashboard_GetProfileStats({'profileid': + profile.id});
     return false;
   });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `onclick` instead of `href`

```
<a href="#" onclick='javascript:dashboard_GetProfileStats({"profileid":"blablabla"});'> ...
```

Comment: You don't need "javascript:..." in an onclick :)